# Move apps to SD card in Marshmallow without using internal SD Card storage?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, 6.0-marshmallow

In previous Android versions is was possible to move apps to the SD Card. In Marshmallow, I was prompted to choose if I want to use My Micro SD Card as external storage or to extend internal storage. I chose to use it as external storage because I need to use it in My computer without a cable. In Marshmallow, the option to transfer apps to SD Card didn't seen to appear. Someone else I know chose to extend internal storage using the Micro SD Card. On that phone, the option still appears. We both have a Moto G2.

Answer (score 1):

Without root and a 3rd party app like [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), it is not possible in Marshmallow because Google removed that capability from Android. If you accept an OTA from Lollipop to Marshmallow, Apps currently on SD will remain there but no additional apps can be moved to the SD card under Marshmallow.

Comment: Can you point to a source on the "Google removed that" part, please, for reference? Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy the references are easy to find in Google, even Motorola has (who used their own branded tool) has it their Marshmallow faq. https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/109134/p/1449,9582

Comment: Ah. While manufacturers sometimes blame this on Google, that's not always the case. And not even done here: "With Android 6.0, **we** are also deprecating the existing ‘Apps 2 SD’" – so *Motorola* no longer supports it. Which doesn't mean *Google* removed it (in fact, as that's a Motorola site, it explicitly says: ***we** are also deprecating the existing ‘Apps 2 SD’ **Motorola** feature which enabled the user to move applications to a SD card*. So unless you've got another link saying it was Google, you might wish to correct that in your answer ;)

Comment: @Izzy I felt that link was more relative to the original question since the original question was about Motorola device, but I know Google did remove that feature from the AOSP code for Marshmallow, it has been replaced by adoptable storage option. I just can't find the reference on my phone and I'm at work now

Comment: OK, agreed on the "closer" due to the Moto G2 :) Other manufacturers (e.g. ASUS) claim the same ([Android Marshmallow won't support APP2SD](http://www.asus.com/zentalk/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=75172)). I don't remember having seen that in the MM release notes, though. If you find that link, would be nice – I'll check for a few more minutes as well.